# P(A|C)=P(A|B)*P(B|C)?

Tags: bayes-theorem

Is this formula P(A|C)=P(A|B)*P(B|C) correct according to Bayes' theorem?
I don't think it correct but for a transition matrice system
we can have something like this[transition matrice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETqd1.png)
So I don't know how to prove P(A|C)=P(A|B)*P(B|C) in transition matrice though it looks very intuitive

Comment: No.  Suppose, to take an extreme case, that $A=C$ but that $A$, $B$ were mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have added something to my original question. Looks like it fit in transition matrice

Comment: That sum is (or at least appears to be) the sum over ALL the transition paths, not just one. [ There's no context for the formula you link to, but let's assume that $X_{n+1}$ can only take one of the values $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.]

Comment: What lulu and the correct answer below are saying is that the transition matrix interpretation should be like this: $P(A \mid C) = P(A\mid B) P(B \mid C)+ P(A \mid B^c)P(B^c \mid C)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what's the formula name of P(A∣C)=P(A∣B)P(B∣C)+P(A∣Bc)P(Bc∣C) or how it get proved?

Answer (score 3):

The correct version of this formula would be
$$
P(A \mid C) = \frac{P(A\mid B) P(B \mid C)P(C) + P(A \mid B^c)P(B^c \mid C)P(C)}{P(C)}
$$
which is, more concisely, 
$$
P(A \mid C) = \frac{P(A \text{ and } C)}{P(C)}
$$

Comment: I have added something to my original question. Looks like it fit in transition matrice

Comment: Shouldn't the numerator be $P(A\mid B\cap C) P(B \mid C)P(C) + P(A \mid B^c\cap C)P(B^c \mid C)P(C)$?

Comment: @grand_chat indeed, this is generally the case. However, from the context (see OP's link) I am guessing that we are looking at a Markov process

Comment: @grand_chat if you think my answer should reflect this, feel free to edit. However, I think the comment should suffice.